VBA code stops in the middle of a for-next loop through a table. What could be going on?
VBA code stops in the middle of a for-next loop through a table
We have an Excel file that loops through a table and based on certain parameters, changes something in a record (row). This looping is in a VBA subroutine, that is part of a bigger subroutine that is triggered through the task scheduler.
We've encountered a few times now that the execution stops somewhere in the middle of the loop (we now have an elaborate logging system). And when the task is started again within 5 minutes, it runs smoothly. Which makes me think that it's not necessarily the Excel file that has a problem, but maybe something with the machine that it's running on?
The problem is also that the file will stay open and potentially is in the way of other tasks that are scheduled after it. We do use a kill-excel command before most tasks, but that can lead to Excel asking to Recover files and wanting an answer (that the task scheduler can't give).
What could be going on? What questions do I have to ask to what specialists to solve this issue?
Edit: clarification on the task-scheduler part.
1. the scheduler is time triggered (00:45)
2. it executes a bat-file that in essence first kills existing instances of Excel and Outlook, then opens the Excel that's one of the parameters and runs a subroutine that is also one of the parameters
This subroutine consists of a few steps
3. determine if it's a bank holiday (updating a power query to an calendar in another file) - exit sub if yes
4. load prices (updating a power query to the prices file)
5. determine if all prices that are needed are actually there (excel formula) - exit sub if not
6. based on the new prices and information that is in each record already there is a helper column that is either true of false, this subroutine loops through the whole database and where the helper column is true, it changes some of the existing values. And in this subroutine the execution stops, sometimes after 10 true's, or 5 or 20. And when there are no true's, it goes onto the next subroutine
7-8-9-10. again a loop through the whole database now with 4 other helper columns.
So far, when the 6th step was done, it got through to the end (= sending out internal e-mails).
A few time I've watched it going 'live' - and stopping 'live' too (cmd window still open, excel open, unresponsive). After killing it all, I just ran the task again, without changing anything, and it would go smoothly.
That's why I suspect it's maybe something happening on the machine that halts all this?
I can't share the file or the VBA code, not even with dummy data, as it would reveal our business formula's.
Could the syncing of SharePoint/OneDrive be in the way? But if so, why not every day but seemingly random?
Edit:
the table is relatively small (I think), 3200 records (only growing slowly), 75 columns.
I've added a 'on error resume next' statement, just in case, and added also an extra 'write-to-log' statement. The code for 6 looks something like this (I'm not at work, so it's parafrasing)
on error resume next
for i = 1 to numbers_of_records
   if value helpercolumn[i] then
        write_to_log("name subroutine before changes "& i) 'write_to_log(1)
        field_x[i] = "something else"
        field_y[i] = "delete what was there"
        write_to_log("name subroutine after changes "& i) 'write_to_log(2)
    else
        'do nothing
   end if
next i 

And this is basically the same for step 7-8-9-10.
This morning the log stopped after write_to_log(1) in the 3 record that met the criterium.
I'll add the DoEvent statements after each line of code (can't hurt, right?) and see what happens.

"excel open, unresponsive" means the VBA code doesn't stop, it's just that Excel itself hangs. What does your elaborate logging system say about the line on which it happens? Can you CTRL+BREAK out of the hang? Does excel.exe consume any CPU when this happens? Do you see any hints in excel.exe's stack trace during the hang? I've encountered strange hangs caused by antivirus-type software, and I don't trust powerquery either, so as others noted many things can go wrong here. Without other clues, I would try to reproduce on a different system (excel/OS versions) or with a simpler file.

I have seen a very intermittent for next loop snafu for large volumes of data in Excel from time to time but never been able to get a decent reproducible MRE for it. One work around that I found and may work for you is to add  a Doevents call to the interior of the loop so that when it locks up terminally you can regain control more elegantly. Killing the process leaves a lot of debris. My best guess is something somewhere overflows but I haven't ever pinned it down.

Perhaps you need to improve the code of step 6. It says you're looping through the records and do something for the ones that have a True somewhere. I would do this differently: Filter the table for the True's and then loop through the visible cells. Or, perhaps even better, read the entire table into a variant array, loop through the variant array and do the magic and then write back the entire variant array.

Can't you post the core of the looping code without the business-sensitive bit? So we might see its structure and advise?

@Nickolay: we're already preparing to run some parallel proces, just for this bit. Meanwhile the live version will continue so we're limited to what we can realistically do. The process runs at 00:45, I'm not paid to work night shifts although occasionally I wake up this in time. It used to run at 5:43, in between al kind of other reporting models on that particular machine. .....

...
The few time that I saw it 'live' it just worked, the few times that I saw it hang I was more concerned with getting my colleagues their data to work with than with in depth analysis. Also because it's so crowded on that machine, I might only have timeslots of 10 minutes. In the middle of the night, not my finest hour for thinking straight. But with your remarks a 'test protocol' is forming in my head. I'll keep you posted.

@jkpieterse I've added the 'core' code to the main question.

Update:
this morning the model didn't finish again (that's the bad news), but the good news is: it got through the step 6 (the module I've last added 'DoEvents' before all lines of code) and got stuck in step 8.
So I've added that code to all modules that loop through this table. Makes the code look really awful, but hey, if it gets the job done....

Have you considered my advice to change the way you're looping?

@jkpieterse yes I've considered it, it's just that I'm not really comfortable with what you suggest, it would require a lot of getting used to and getting to trust what happens is what I intend to happen. Haven't used array-variants that often, if ever.
I will come back to it if all other changes that I've so far implemented turn out to fail. First we'll have me looking live at the model and when it fails assess memory use, what else is happening on the machine etc . For a few days only as I don't want to turn into a night owl.
